# SQL Bulk Insert Errors: How to a priori identify problems using Python/Pandas?

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

I have a bunch of tables that I am copying to data lake for storage as CSV files so that I may later use those files to bulk insert with. Consequently, I am getting a number of bulk insert errors, as far as I can tell, mostly from free-text columns that I think are incorporating commas, quotes, and the like.

How can I use pandas / python to investigate these data sets before hand, to figure out how I might craft a bulk insert statement correctly?

My insert statement looks roughly like:

```
            BULK INSERT table
            FROM 'file.csv'
            WITH (
                DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureStorage',
                FORMAT = 'CSV',
                FIRSTROW = 2,
                FIELDTERMINATOR=',',
                DATAFILETYPE='char',
                ROWTERMINATOR='0x0a',
                KEEPNULLS,
                TABLOCK)
```

I also have the flexibility through Azure Synapse to specify how my CSV export file handles:

1. Column delimiter
2. Row delimiter
3. Escape character
4. Quote character

Comment: Sounds like your data isn't actually valid CSV, as commas would be enclosed in quotes and should parse fine

Comment: What version of SQL Server is this? SQL Server 2017 CTP 1.1 and later support RFC 4180 CSV files (where field data can contain commas, newlines and quotes) when using the [`FORMAT='CSV'` option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql#format--csv). Previous versions don't support embedded commas, newlines and quotes.